# kubernetes cluster cant intilized

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubernetes-cluster

I'm creating kubernetes cluster on fedora 26, but I can't initialize cluster on kubernetes.

Here I'm attaching images and error for your references, guide me how to solve the issue..

**Environment:**

- Docker Version
- Client Version: 1.13.1
- API version: 1.26

**Kubeadm version:**

[image: Kubeadm version]

**Error Image:**

[image: Error Image]

**Cluster Error:**

[image: Cluster Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your setup is that the minimum required CPU to install Kubernetes with kubeadm is 2 and you have only 1 CPU on your VM.

If you want to setup kubernetes on single machine, please have a look at microK8s. Following is the step by step instruction to install it on Fedora:

> https://itnext.io/a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s-33ee31d1eed9

Comment: you can also use minikube, but other than that - error points that this is  the problem.

Comment: The problem with minikube is it generates another VM on top of it, which also by default requires 2 CPU. You can configure it and increase the number of CPU but not sure if you can decrease it to 1.

Comment: from what I know minikube actually uses 1 CPU and 1 GB of  RAM which can be increased.

Comment: I just checked with latest version of minikube using `minikube start -h` . This is what I found
     --cpus int                       Number of CPUs allocated to the minikube VM (default 2)

Comment: You are right, I also found confirmation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/232080ae0cbcf9cb9a388eb76cc11cf6884e19c0/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L102) . Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can run `kubeadm init` with only one CPU added: `--ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU`. So your new code:

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU`